# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funciones' (Python)

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to create some diccionary with some functions for some repetitive tasks where I work, and now when I try to use any function on the dicc I have this error.
I'm also learning python, there's like 2 weeks i'm proggraming in this language, so if anybody can help me to approach the problem in a more specific way, I'll be very grateful.

That's the folders structure:
[folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSlbL.png)

here is how I'm importing the functions, storing and invoking function

```
 #Funciones Cred Now ------------------
from funciones.credNowFunciones.CredNowLoanCargar import credNowLoanCargar
from funciones.credNowFunciones.CredNowLoanCargar import credNowLoanCargarYComparar
from funciones.credNowFunciones.CredNowLoanAcumulable import credNowLoanAcumulable

credNowDict = {
    "cargarLoan": credNowLoanCargar,
    "cargarYCompararLoan": credNowLoanCargarYComparar,
    "loanAcumulable": credNowLoanAcumulable
}

#Invocar funciones
credNowDict['cargarLoan']('archivos/excels/credNow/1-100-CXXXNXw_1102.xlsx',
'archivos/generadosPorEmpresa/credNowGenerados/crxxNxxnxCargar.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `from package.subpackage.module import object` structure only works if `package` and `subpackage` are valid packages - that is, they are in a directory on the `PYTHONPATH` or in the same directory as the `__main__` file, containing a file called `__init__.py`.

Because neither `funciones` nor `credNowFunciones` contain a file called `__init__.py`, they do not count as packages and cannot be imported properly. To solve this, simply add an empty `__init__.py` file into each of the folders which you want to be able to import from, so the folder structure of `funciones` becomes like this:

```
funciones/
  __init__.py
  credNowFunciones/
    __init__.py
    CredNowLoanAcumulable.py
    CredNowLoanCargar.py
  edemsaFunciones/
    __init__.py
    ...
```

Also note that if the python script you are importing the objects into is not in the same directory as `funciones`, you need to make sure `funciones` is in a directory which is on your `PYTHONPATH`. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pythonpath-environment-variable-in-python/) for more info.

For more information on Python packages, see [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!! I had a permision problem and I could prove the solution just today. It was very clear and helpful.